# How to access global variable

Tags: python

From the following code, I wish for the output of names to contain an array of names taken from a column in a csv file. When the function is run, the array remains empty. Why?

```
def cp_identifier():
    global names
    names = []
    array_dec()
    print(names)

def array_dec():
    with open("card_list_currents.csv", "r") as file:
        card_list_table = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=',')
        for row in card_list_table:
            names.append(row["Card Name"])
```

**Current Output:**

```
[]
```

**Expected output:**

```
['Card Name', 'Card Name', ... , 'Card Name']
```

Answer (score 5):

Why dont you use something like the following, rather than using a `global variable`

```
def cp_identifier():
    names = array_dec()
    print(names)
    return names

def array_dec():
    names = []
    with open("card_list_currents.csv", "r") as file:
        card_list_table = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=',')

        for row in card_list_table:
            names.append(row["Card Name"])
    return names
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    names = cp_identifier()
    print(names)
```

Comment: the question contains `cp_identifier` as the function name

Comment: It still returns an empty array

Comment: how do you call the `cp_identifier` function

Comment: if __name__ == "__main__":
    cp_identifier()

Comment: I have revised the solution, can you check now. Let me know if you not getting the desired output

Comment: The array is still empty. I'm trying to make the array global because I have another function that is comparing a string to the string elements inside the array. It seems to work when I include opening the csv in the function where I compare the strings but I don't want to have the script opening the csv everytime I want to compare strings. I was trying to store the elements into an array which I can instead use to compare the string with

Comment: can you share the entire code,

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to use a `global` variable then following is a better way to declare `global names`

```
global names

def cp_identifier():
    #global names
    names = []
    array_dec()
    print(names)

def array_dec():
    with open("card_list_currents.csv", "r") as file:
        card_list_table = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=',')
        for row in card_list_table:
            names.append(row["Card Name"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `names` is global to `cp_identifier` but not to `array_dec`. In the latter `names` is a local variable that is thrown away after the call.

However, avoid globals whenever possible. You can just return the `names` array from `array_dec`.